# Black screen after waking from suspend Ubuntu Budgie 18.10

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-budgie

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu Budgie 18.10 installed on it. When I'm using the integrated graphics card from Intel (by issuing `sudo prime-select intel`) everything works smoothly, but when I select the NVIDIA dedicated graphics card (issuing `sudo prime-select nvidia`) I can't wake from suspend: when I re-open the lid after having closed it, the screen remains black. I can tell that the system actually woke up because the fan makes some noise and the keyboard's backlight works fine.

My dedicated graphics card is the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, and the driver version is 390.87

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the key that increases the screen brightness? I'm on an earlier Ubuntu (Lenovo with NVidia graphics), but this also happens to me from time to time, and hitting the key is enough to get get a visible screen.

Answer (score 0):

I use a XPS 15 too and have à lot of issues with nvidia drivers and ubuntu.

Ty to configure grub like this :

Edit the file /etc/default/grub :

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Replace default grub cmdline with this one (adapt it if needed):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

Good luck !